# Is there a way to pass in a ofstream reference to a object?

Tags: c++, oop, object, reference, ofstream

I'm trying to pass a reference to an ofstream with an open file to an object, so that it's functions can also print to the file.

When I try to compile my program, it says that all reference members must be initialized, and I read online that streams cannot be reassigned. So what do I do?

Here's what I have for my constructors:

```
GameShow::GameShow(int numElements){

    // Initialize heap
    v = new Contestant[numElements+1];
    capacity = numElements+1;
    size = 0;
}


GameShow(int numElements, std::ofstream &of)
: outFile(of){

        // Initialize heap
    v = new Contestant[numElements+1];
    capacity = numElements+1;
    size = 0;
    outputToFile = true;
    handle.reserve(numElements+1);
    handle.resize(numElements+1, -1);
}
```

And here is my declaration in my header file:

```
// Members
....
ofstream &outFile;
....
GameShow(int numElements);
GameShow(int numElements, std::ofstream &of);
....
```

I have the ofstream open in my main() function, but my object's functions need to be able to modify the same file... I feel like I've tried everything.

When I tried passing in the name of the file and trying to open it in append mode in the object and print to it, the output was all out of order and completely out of sync with the output from my main function. It seems as though all of the print statements I call from my object are being held in a buffer until my main function has closed the stream on its end.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Attempting to use the constructor in my main function:

```
       // Attempt to open output file
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(outFileName);

    if(inFile.is_open()){
            if(outFile.is_open()){
                    // Get information
                    int numContestants = 0;
                    inFile >> numContestants;


                    // Process file
                    if(numContestants > 0){
                            GameShow gs(numContestants, outFile);
```

Errors (the only one im getting):

```
GameShow.cpp: In constructor ‘GameShow::GameShow(int)’:
GameShow.cpp:27:1: error: uninitialized reference member in ‘std::ofstream& {aka class std::basic_ofstream<char>&}’ [-fpermissive]
 GameShow::GameShow(int numElements){
 ^
GameShow.h:14:18: note: ‘std::ofstream& GameShow::outFile’ should be initialized
std::ofstream &outFile;
              ^
make: *** [GameShow.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Don't declare a reference (`ofstream &outFile;`), declare an object and pass that object, by reference, to the function.

Comment: @MariusBancila I guess that's my only choice.  There's really no way to pass a reference to an object??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as you've shown it. Show the rest of it, along with more precise error messages.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Give me a minute, will post

Comment: @JayB What you're asking is how to initialize an object's reference data member. You should post an MCVE with code that fails, because in principle it should not be a problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza On it...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Posted usage with error messages.

Comment: @juanchopanza No need for an mcve here i don't think (correct me if I'm wrong), my edit shows everything. just updated the question

Comment: I think you need the MCVE. At least that way we can see if the problem has anything to do with what you're reporting, of is something unrelated (like using an undeclared variable.)

Comment: yeah it was just the other constructor, I didn't realize that the ofstream still had to be initialized in the other constructor since I don't use it in my program, just took it out and all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference members cannot be left uninitialized. You need to initialize `outFile` in the `GameShow(int numElements)` constructor as well.

Comment: Ah, ok I have an override of the constructor without the ofstream parameter...I didn't make that connection, that should fix it.

Comment: And if you need a reference that you may not always be able to initialize, or one which you may need to change what it refers to, that's what a pointer is for.

Comment: I was thinking that, but if I pass in the address to an ofstream pointer. What would be the syntax? Would i just (*ofstream) << "output"?

Comment: Yes that would be the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

From the error messages, it seems that you have another constructor:

```
GameShow(int numElements);
```

In the implementation of that constructor, you are not initializing the variable `outFile`. I am not sure what would be an appropriate value to initialize that variable to. If you change your variable to type `std::ostream`, you could initialize it to `std::cout`.

Comment: You can initialize an ofstream to cout? Can you provide syntax on how to do that? I've never heard of such

Comment: No, not an `ofstream` but an `ostream`. I missed that.

Comment: I'm just going to delete the other constructor, it's currently unused anyway. Thanks for the spot I so clearly missed

Answer (score 0):

Instead on reference as member user pointer.

ofstream *outFile;

....

GameShow(int numElements, std::ofstream *of);

Comment: sorry typing mistake .
Instead on reference as member user pointer.

ofstream *outFile;
....
GameShow(int numElements, std::ofstream &of);

Comment: Thanks,  juanchopanza. I am new to this platform.